# Basic Pandas data analysis: connecting data types

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I loaded in a dataframe where there is a variable called natvty which is a frequency of numbers from 50 - 600. Each number represents a country and each country appears more than once. I did a count of the number of times each country appears in the list. Now I would like to replace the number of the country with the name of the country, for example (57 = United States). I tried all kinds of for loops to no avail. Here's my code thus far. In the value counts table, the country number is on the left and the number of times it appears in the data is on the right. I need to replace the number on the left with the country name. The numbers which correspond to country names are in an external excel sheet in two columns. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be no need to REPLACE the country numbers with country names at first. Since you have now two tables, one is with columns `["country_number", "natvty"]` and the other (your excel table, can be exported as `.csv` file and read by `pandas`) is with columns `["country_number", "country_name"]`, so you can simply join them both and keep them all. The resulted table would have 3 columns:  `["country_number", "natvty", "country_name"]`, respectively.

```
import pandas as pd

df_nav    = pd.read_csv("my_natvty.csv")
df_cnames = pd.read_csv("excel_country_names.csv") # or use pd.read_excel("country_names.xlsx") directly on excel files

df_nav_with_cnames = df_nav.join(df_cnames, on='country_number')
```

Make sure they both have a column `"country_number"`. You can modify the table head in the data source files manually, or treat them as `index columns` to apply `join` similarly. The concept is a little bit like SQL operations in relational databases.

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: There is also [`pd.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), so no need to export Excel to CSV.

Comment: @IgorRaush Yep, that's a good choice of course. But I wish the data analyst people could use more transparent and standardized formats whenever accessibility is not an issue :)

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I always prefer the `map` function, which eats a dictionary, or a function for that matter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as np
In [12]:

print 
# generate data
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'natvty':np.randint(low=20,high=500,size=10),
                        'country':pd.Series([1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,3])})
df
   country  natvty
0        1      24
1        2     310
2        3      88
3        3     459
4        3      38
5        2      63
6        1     194
7        1     384
8        2     281
9        3     360
```

Then, the `dict`. Here I just type it, but you could load it from a csv or excel file. Then you'd want to set the key as the index and turn the resulting series into a dict (`to_dict()`).

```
countrymap = {1:'US',2:'Canada',3:'Mexico'}
```

Then you can simply `map` the value labels.

```
df.country.map(countrymap)
Out[10]:
0        US
1    Canada
2    Mexico
3    Mexico
4    Mexico
5    Canada
6        US
7        US
8    Canada
9    Mexico
Name: country, dtype: objec
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: *The basic idea here is the same as [Shellay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615899/1391671). I just wanted to demonstrate how to handle different column names in the two data frames, and how to retrieve the per-country frequencies you wanted.*

You have one data frame containing country codes, and another data frame which maps country codes to country names. You simply need to join them on the country code columns. You can read more about [merging in Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [SQL joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
import pandas as pd

# this is your nativity frame
nt = pd.DataFrame([
    [123],
    [123],
    [456],
    [789],
    [456],
    [456]
], columns=('natvty',))

# this is your country code map
# in reality, use pd.read_excel
cc = pd.DataFrame([
    [123, 'USA'],
    [456, 'Mexico'],
    [789, 'Canada']
], columns=('country_code', 'country_name'))

# perform a join
# now each row has an associated country_name
df = nt.merge(cc, left_on='natvty', right_on='country_code')

# now you can get frequencies on country names instead of country codes
print df.country_name.value_counts(sort=False)
```

The output from the above is

```
Canada    1
USA       2
Mexico    3
Name: country_name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, just realized my question was a bit ambiguous because I didn't provide the format of the original data, but this answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think a dictionary would be your best bet. If you had a dict of the countries and their codes e.g.

```
country_dict = {333: 'United States', 123: 'Canada', 456: 'Cuba', ...}
```

You presumably have a key of the countries and their codes, so you could make the dict really easily with a loop:

```
country_dict = {}
for i in country_list:
    country = i[0]  # If you had list of countries and their numbers
    number = i[1]
    country_dict[number] = country
```

Adding a column to your DataFrame once you have this should be straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', header=None)
df['country'] = [country_dict[x[0][i]] for i in list(df.index)]
```

This should work if the country codes column has index 0

Comment: This will not work. `df[1]` will return a `Series` object containing all country codes, which cannot be used as a key to a plain Python dictionary.